# Reduce list of value / date array to last x days and add missing days

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have the following JSON and I would like to get an array only including the last x days, and fill the gaps (days without any values) with the days and `completed` and `started` as 0:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2019-04-14T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":6
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-04-18T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":3,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-05-19T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-09-16T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":1,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":2
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-10T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-06-20T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-07-28T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":4
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-07-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-07-16T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-27T22:00:00.000Z",
      "completed":0,
      "started":1
   }
]
```

I don't find a way to go on. I was inititially coming from an object where I had several entries for the same date and managed to do this consolidation, but now I am lost. Any ideas? I thought about `filter` or `reduce` but I don't know how to apply them.

Thanks!

Desired output:

```
[
   {
      "date": ((today - 7 days)),
      "completed": ...,
      "started": ...
   },
   {
      "date": ((today - 6 days)),
      "completed": ...,
      "started": ...
   },
   {
      "date": ((today - 5 days)),
      "completed": ...,
      "started": ...
   }
]
```

Where ((today - x days)) is the date of the last 7 days and "completed" and started" contain the values from above or if not available each 0.

Comment: Can you include an example of the desired output?

Comment: I have added it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to keep only the entries from the last x days (I'm using x in this code as a variable to represent that number of days):

```
const lastXDays = data.filter(entry => {
  const daysSince = (Date.now() - (new Date(entry.date)).getTime())/1000/60/60/24;
  return daysSince <= x;
});
```

Then to fill in the extra days, since these timestamps are all at the same time of day (22:00:00), you can sort by date and just add 1 day's worth of milliseconds to the minimum until you reach the maximum, inserting when there's no match to the currently checked time:

```
const sortedDays = lastXDays.sort((a,b) => a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime());
const maxTime = sortedDays[sortedDays.length - 1].date.getTime();
const minTime = sortedDays[0].date.getTime();
const output = [];
for (let timeToCheck = minTime; timeToCheck <= maxtime; timeToCheck += 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {
    const existing = sortedDays.find(day => day.date.getTime() === timeToCheck);
    if (existing) {
      output.push(existing);
    } else {
      output.push({
        date: new Date(timeToCheck),
        completed: 0,
        started: 0
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect! :) I did two changes to minTime and maxTime, as I always wanted to have the last x days (the minTime in the complicated way to have the same local timezone (+2 in my case).
```  const minTime = (new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate())).getTime() - x * (1000*60*60*24);
  const maxTime = today.getTime();
```

Comment: The calculation of the last X days doesn't happen from maxTime and minTime, it happens in the filter callback from lastXDays. maxTime and minTime are just getting the maximum and minimum times that exist in the resulting filtered array, as bounds of the loop. If you don't set minTime based on the array, you're likely to get duplicate days in the array as they won't match the existing entries during the "filling in" process.